# How to find which field value has find query worked in mongo-db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am writing a $or query in the mongo shell

```
db.collectionName.find({$or:[{ fullName: { $regex: "a",$options:"i"}},{ fullName: { $regex: "b",$options:"i"}}]}).pretty();
```

It gives me the documents matching the union of a or b. But can we also find which value has the query worked and given the result? Like for first regex i.e. "a" I get a separate result and for the other one i.e. "b" I get a separate result

Comment: Hi, Do you want to [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) the results?

Comment: @HanielBaez if that can solve my problem why not

Answer (score 0):

Using the aggregation pipeline documents enter a multi-stage pipeline that transforms the documents into aggregated results, having said that.

Stage explanation:

1. $match: It is similar to the a find operation.
2. [$addFields:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) Ass
   the name suggest it add a field, in this case call `byRegex`,
   matching one of the matching regex query.
3. $group: Group the document
   by the already created `byRegex` field and push then into a array
   field call documents.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    $or: [
      {
        fullName: {
          "$regex": "a",
          "$options": "i"
        }
      },
      {
        fullName: {
          "$regex": "b",
          "$options": "i"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "$addFields": {
    "byRegex": {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          "$regexMatch": {
            "input": "$fullName",
            "regex": "a",
            "options": "i"
          }
        },
        then: "a",
        else: "b"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$byRegex",
    documents: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
});
```

Please, take some time to understand the [performance implication of regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html#index-use).